OpenAI API: Is the /v1/chat/completions endpoint a legacy endpoint?
Goal
I am currently working on a project where I am integrating GPT-3.5 models into my application.
Problem
However, I have encountered an issue where only gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct seems to be working with the /v1/chat/completions endpoint. When I try to use other GPT-3.5 and GPT-4 models, I receive the following error:

Error code: 404 - {‘error’: {‘message’: ‘This is a chat model and not
supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use
v1/chat/completions?’, ‘type’: ‘invalid_request_error’, ‘param’:
‘model’, ‘code’: None}}

Does this mean that the /v1/completions endpoint is deprecated for other GPT-3.5 and GPT-4 models? Or am I missing something in my setup?
For context, I have already added $5 to my OpenAI account, so I believe I should have access to the models. I would appreciate any guidance on whether this issue is due to endpoint deprecation or if there’s a different recommended approach to using other GPT-3.5 and GPT-4 models with the /v1/chat/completions endpoint.
What I've tried
Attempt 1
Model initialization:
from langchain_openai import OpenAI
llm = OpenAI(model='gpt-4-turbo')

Attempt 2
Attempted to use other GPT-3.5 and GPT-4 models with the /v1/chat/completions endpoint.
I received the aforementioned 404 error.
Conclusion
I expected that other GPT-3.5 and GPT-4 models would work with the /v1/chat/completions endpoint without encountering a 404 error. Specifically, I expected to be able to interchangeably use different GPT-3.5 models with this endpoint for generating completions.
For context, I have already added $5 to my OpenAI account, so I believe I should have access to the models.
I would appreciate any guidance on whether this issue is due to endpoint deprecation or if there's a different recommended approach to using other GPT-3.5 and GPT-4 models with the /v1/chat/completions endpoint.
Thank you!

it sounds like you have to pay more.

I'll try to clear things up for you.
Q: Is the /v1/chat/completions API endpoint a legacy endpoint?
A: No. The /v1/completions API endpoint is a legacy endpoint.
Q: Is the /v1/completions API endpoint deprecated for GPT-3.5 Turbo and GPT-4 models?
A: This is the wrong question. GPT-3.5 Turbo and GPT-4 models are not compatible with the /v1/completions API endpoint. It's not that the endpoint is deprecated. Its GPT-3.5 Turbo and GPT-4 models are not compatible with it.
See the official OpenAI documentation on endpoint compatibility.



ENDPOINT
LATEST MODELS




/v1/assistants
All GPT-4 and GPT-3.5 Turbo models except gpt-3.5-turbo-0301 supported. The retrieval tool requires gpt-4-turbo-preview (and subsequent dated model releases) or gpt-3.5-turbo-1106 (and subsequent versions).


/v1/audio/transcriptions
whisper-1


/v1/audio/translations
whisper-1


/v1/audio/speech
tts-1, tts-1-hd


/v1/chat/completions
gpt-4 and dated model releases, gpt-4-turbo-preview and dated model releases, gpt-4-vision-preview, gpt-4-32k and dated model releases, gpt-3.5-turbo and dated model releases, gpt-3.5-turbo-16k and dated model releases, fine-tuned versions of gpt-3.5-turbo


/v1/completions (Legacy)
gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct, babbage-002, davinci-002


/v1/embeddings
text-embedding-3-small, text-embedding-3-large, text-embedding-ada-002


/v1/fine_tuning/jobs
gpt-3.5-turbo, babbage-002, davinci-002


/v1/moderations
text-moderation-stable, text-moderation-latest


/v1/images/generations
dall-e-2, dall-e-3



